# What does {$x$} mean?

Tags: functions, notation

What does {$x$} mean in terms of $x$? I'm not really sure about anything on this so please explain as thoroughly as possible. Thanks!

Comment: In what contexts have you encountered this?

Comment: But, loosely speaking, $x$ is an object, while $\{x\}$ is the set containing that object (and only that object)

Comment: I have seen it as the fractional part of $x$, so $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$.  It can also be the set whose only member is $x$.  The context should make it clear.

Comment: Depends on context but I imagine it is probably the fractional part of the real number $x$.  If $x \in \mathbb R$ then there is a unique integer $n$, so that $n \le x < n+1$.  That means there is a unique number $r$ so that $x = n + r$ and $r = x-n$ and $0 \le r < 1$.  We say that $n$ is the "greatest integer less or equal to $x$" or "the floor of $x$".  We write it as $n = \lfloor x \rfloor$. And we say $r$ is "the fractional part of $x$" and write it as $\{x\}$.  One way to think of it is:  "$\{x\}$ is how much over an integer you have to go to get to $x$.

Comment: .... A practical example could be: As $\pi = 3.141592653....$ and $3 \le \pi < 4$ and $\pi = 3 + 0.141592653....$ we have $\rfloor \pi \lfloor  = 3$ and $\{\pi\} = 0.141592653....$.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint:
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} :x=\lfloor x \rfloor +\{x\} $$for example
$$x=3.53 \to \lfloor x \rfloor=3 , \{x\}=0.53\\x=4\to \lfloor x \rfloor=4 , \{x\}=0 \\x=-3.7 \to \lfloor x \rfloor=-4 , \{x\}=+0.3$$ also you can rewrite $\{x\}=x- \lfloor x \rfloor$ for the last example $$x=-3.7 \to \lfloor x \rfloor=-4 \\\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor=-3.7-(-4)=+0.3$$ and finally $$0\le \{x\} <1$$

Comment: Yes, I got it, it's the decimal/fractional part of the number e.g. {3.7}=0.7 {$pi$}=0.14159265358979...